# getting value from xml in a dict

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file that I want to parse. In the file I have 3 unique tags - 
3
2
1

Each of these have 1 unique value for a metricX. I want to be extract these values in form a dict in python. 
Something like

```
   Desired Output          
   { 3 : {"metricX":100}, 2 : {"metricX":11}, 1 : {"metricX":44}}


    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataCollection.xsl"?>
    <!DOCTYPE mdc SYSTEM "MeasDataCollection.dtd">
    <mdc xmlns:HTML="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml">
    <md>
    <neid>
    <neun>936001_STURGEON_BAY_MEYER</neun>
    </neid>
    <mi>
    <mi>
    <mts>20170924161500Z</mts>
    <gp>900</gp>
    <mt>metricX</mt>
    <mv>
    <moid>3</moid>
    <r>100</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
    <moid>2</moid>
    <r>11</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
    <moid>1</moid>
    <r>44</r>
    </mv>
    </mi>
    </mi>
    </md>
    </mdc>
```

So far I have tried using Element Tree.

```
 import os
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
  fullpath = os.getcwd()
  os.chdir(r"C:\Users\sss\Documents\Zabbix_work\xml_parsing")
  tree = ET.ElementTree(file='smaple.xml')
  for elem in tree.iter():
      print (elem.tag, elem.text)
```

Output so far is -

```
    mdc 

    md 

    neid 

    neun 936001_STURGEON_BAY_MEYER
    mi 

    mi 

    mts 20170924161500Z
    gp 900
    mt metricX
    mv 

    moid 3
    r 100
    mv 

    moid 2
    r 11
    mv 

    moid 1
    r 44
```

Not so sure now how to organize it further in form of a dict.

Comment: sounds good. what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: Added some results that I have gotten so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/input123.xml') # filepath here

tree = ET.ElementTree(file=file_path)

my_dict = {}

for node in tree.getroot().find('md').find('mi').find('mi').findall('mv'):
    my_dict[int(node.find('moid').text)] = { 'metricX': int(node.find('r').text) }

print(my_dict)
```

...output:

`{3: {'metricX': 100}, 2: {'metricX': 11}, 1: {'metricX': 44}}`